# Reading a large file from S3 into a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

when i try to read a file more than 2GB in size to a dataframe
i get followinbg error: OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum

this is as mentioned in https://bugs.python.org/issue42853

is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in the bug use read the file using the buffer. remember you are still loading the data into your ram. so your system should still have large enough ram to store the data. or you will out of memory error.

existing code

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource()
s3_client = boto3.client()

s3_obj = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name, filename).get()
    with io.BytesIO(s3_obj["Body"].read()) as file:
        file_as_df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding='latin1',sep='\t')
```

revised code

```
response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket= bucket_name , Key = filename)
#os.path.join(key, datafile) #ignore this
buf = bytearray(response['ContentLength'])
view = memoryview(buf)
pos = 0
while True:
    chunk = response['Body'].read(67108864)
    if len(chunk) == 0:
        break
    view[pos:pos+len(chunk)] = chunk
    pos += len(chunk)

file_as_df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(bytes(view)), encoding='latin1',sep='\t')
```